# React app slows to a crawl only in developer mode

Tags: reactjs, performance, webpack

We have a React app. Lately we are experiencing an issue which only appears in "developer" mode. Two of the modules causes the app to become unresponsive for several seconds. The cpu works hard and memory usage spikes. If I change the settings in Webpack to "production" it works smoothly.

I have tried doing performance recordings in devtools, but I am unable to interpret anything useful from it.

I have tried making the Webpack configuration as simple as possible without any signs of improvement.

I am not posting any code since I don't really know where the issue(s) might be. But maybe someone can give some ideas about where to look or how we can pinpoint the issue.

[image]

[image]

[image: These DOM events look suspicious]

Comment: You can export the performance results so other can review it and help answer your question.

Comment: The dev build has a lot of tooling which slows things down, but it should still be responsive. Just because it "works" in the prod build doesn't mean there isn't a problem there as well, so be cautious.

Comment: They key to fixing this problem is to see which function keeps the browser busy, can you add a screenshot of the performance tab investigation please?

Comment: I have added screenshots from a recording of the perforance during the slowdown. I noticed that there is a long list of similar and identical DOM events. That looks suspicious.

Comment: I can see you have some tracker for state mutations. And obviously you are not running it in production. That one is probably causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks @noitse! See my answer :-)

Comment: Glad to help. Also, I would recommend `use strict` and `Object.freeze` on your store to catch mutations in development, instead of low-performance middlewares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @noitse for pinpointing the problem. I removed "[redux-immutable-state-invariant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-immutable-state-invariant)" and that fixed the problem.